# Same class name in different package

Tags: java

I have a scenario where I have to create a method signature with same class name but from different package. The below code is causing compile time exception. How can we resolve this?
Here is the methods:

```
import com.mitali.api.Employee;
class Fetcher {
    void boolean getFromEmployee(Employee emp) {}

    void boolean getFromEmployeeModel(com.mitali.api.model.Employee emp) {}

}
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to "resolve?"  What is the error message?  You don't show what package you are using or the other class, maybe you should post complete code.

Comment: `void boolean` is not a valid return type.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're getting an error because a method cannot return void and boolean at the same time

Answer (score 0):

```java
import com.mitali.api.Employee;

class Fetcher {
    void /*boolean*/ getFromEmployee(Employee emp) {}

    void /*boolean*/ getFromEmployeeModel(com.mitali.api.model.Employee emp) {}

}
```

Method shouold retrieve either `void` or `boolean` in you snippet.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the void and boolean is a typo.
Here is a quick solution:

```
class Fetcher {
    class ApiV1 {
        boolean getFromEmployee(Employee emp) {
        }
    }
    
    class ApiV2 {
        boolean getFromEmployeeModel(com.mitali.api.model.Employee emp)   {
        }
    }
}
```